# Reshaping a dense layer into a convolutional filter - Dynamic convolutional filter

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Is there a way to re-shape a dense layer into a convolutional filter?

Say I have two inputs: Input_tabular_layer and Input_image_layer where the image is RGB (so of depth = 3) and a layer:

```
layer_1 = Dense(2*(5*5)*3, activation = 'sigmoid')(Input_tabular_layer)
```

Would it be possible to construct a

```
conv_layer_1 = Conv2D(filters = 2, kernel_size = (5,5), activation = linear, weights = layer_1)(Input_image)
```

or in other words

```
conv_layer_1 = reshape(layer_1)
```

and to pass it as a filter?
I'd also want to be able to train a model using such a layer.